# Button click that sends user to aboutus.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have been having trouble finding a way to send the user to an xml once they click the about us button on the activity_main.xml

**MainActivity**
I declare the ArrayAdapter here which is created in da_menu.xml

```
package com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/*
This app is for a local Vape Shop
 it's purpose is to increase customer flow, and provide a menu for Android users

 the array is going to be called = da_menu
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /*
    called when the user clicks the send Button
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        populateListView();
    }


    private void populateListView() {
        // Create the list of items

        String[] juiceMenu= {
                "#1 BlueBerry Bombshell",
                "#2 Richie Rich",
                "#3 Chiquita",
                "#4 Afternoon Delight",
                "#5 Poppin Otters",
                "#6 Viva La Sangria",
                "#7 Okole Maluna",
                "#8 Carmen Miranda",
                "#9 Pomalade",
                "#10 Izual",
                "#11 Butter Stotch",
                "#12 Blue Bulls",
                "#13 Grape Ape",
                "#14 Bruce Juice",
                "#15 Doc Holiday",
                "#16 Peachy Keen",
                "#17 Hula",
                "#18 New York",
                "#19 Al Gore",
                "#20 Lux Charms",
                "#21 Sailor Jack",
                "#22 Get Him to the Greek",
                "#23 Key We Lie Chi",
                "#24 Spring Fling",
                "#25 Gumby",
                "#26 Chai-Milk",
                "#27 Mr. Bean",
                "#28 50 Shades of Orange",
                "#29 Blue Waffles",
                "#30 Enigma",
                "#31 Mr. Freeze",
                "#32 Cup of Joe"};
        // Build adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,               // context for the activity
                R.layout.da_menu,   // Layout to create
                juiceMenu);         // Items to be displayed

        //configure list view
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**Activty_main.xml**
here I display the ArrayAdapter in the ListView

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFAFA"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.vitoriano_vaz.eastbayvapes.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Welcome to East Bay Vapes"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listViewMain"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonAboutUs" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About Us"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAboutUs"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**aboutus.xml**
this is the xml i want to send the user to once they have clicked the buttonAboutUs
I am constantly running into problems and cant seem to find a valid solution. I have tried ViewSwitcher but could not seem to get it to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8800FF"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
    android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="About Us"
            android:id="@+id/AboutUs"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

         <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="bayvapes@gmail.com"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AboutUs" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="1555 S Vasco RD Liver, Ca 94551"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
            android:text="(925)-961-9000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
            android:text="facebook.com/bayvapes"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:text="Instagram: @bayvapes"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
            android:text="Monday - Saturday 10:00 am - 8:00 pm\n Sunday 10:00 am - 6:00 pm"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</
```

Comment: Create an activity or a fragment and set `aboutus.xml` layout to it. Then simply launch that activity/fragment on button click.

Comment: basically create a aboutus.class and once the button is clicked launch it to the aboutus.class
would i call to the class via an Intent

Comment: Implement the  android:onClick="onClick" method in your MainActivity. And create an activity/fragment with aboutus.xml layout,Use intent to navigate from list activity to about activity.

Comment: @CosmoVitoriano yes, launch the activity via an `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

First add a button to your `activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me" />
```

And find this view in `MainActivity.java`

```
Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Now Create a new Activity you calls it **AboutUs** add your data to show in `about_us.xml`

Now write this `ClickListener` for button's click in `MainActivity.java`.

```
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.java,AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(intent);
             //This intent will send you on next activity
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have already added a button to my activity_main.xml it is located at the bottom

Comment: ok find the `button` and add `clicklistener` as i write in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity define a onClick method like this.

```
    public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class); // this is AboutUs activity
            startActivity(intent); // start the intent to go to AboutUs Screen
        }
```

you're missing above method in your MainActivity Class

Answer (score 0):

Create an Activity like AboutActivity.class and add it in you manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".AboutActivity"/>
```

Now create the following method in your MainActivity.class

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
        //This will send user to your about activity
        startActivity(intent);
        }
```